# Python integration in Qlik on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, qlikview, qliksense

I'm very new to using Qlik and at the moment I've only used the cloud via my browser. I would like to integrate python and Qlik such that I can run my code on data in the QlikCloud and visualize using Qlik. I am using a Mac, therefore I can not install the desktop version of Qlik to do the integration.
Do you have any suggestions on how to integrate python in Qlik while using a Mac?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated, I have not been able to find any complete answers yet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use Data Load Script

When I first started Qlik, I had a very similar situation. My goal was to manipulate data to do calculations in Python, then basically import that into Qlik. What I ended up learning and realizing is that there's a 90% chance what you're trying to calculate outside of Qlik can be done in Qlik's **data load script**.

Get started with the Qlik data script: https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2019/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/introduction-data-modeling.htm

In my opinion and experience, Qlik Community Forum is more active than Stack Overflow. I highly recommend checking it out for help: https://community.qlik.com/

---

## But If You Still Need External Calculation...

That said, if you do have crazy calculations and math to do and/or need to use an external "thing", Qlik has a repo for a server-side extension. Repo at: https://github.com/qlik-oss/server-side-extension *(Docs and instructions in the link)*

It has extensions for Java, C++, C#, Go, and Python.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will most certainly have a look at the Qlik community forum in that case!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend this Server Side Extension developed by Nabeel which you can run in a docker on your machine. https://github.com/nabeel-oz/qlik-py-tools